# What will happen if I run 'rosclean purge'?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using ROS kinetic on ununtu 16.04.

This question might not be serious, and it does not bring up any other problems.

I got the following warning every time when my roscore runs:

```
WARNING: disk usage in log directory [/home/robotics/.ros/log] is over 1GB.
It's recommended that you use the 'rosclean' command.
```

I also referenced to [this issue](https://answers.ros.org/question/195630/roscore-warning/), but I just afraid this command might spoil my ROS system in some ways.

The above instruction says maybe `rosclean purge` can remove that warning, but I'm not still sure.
Would it truely going to be ok if I run `rosclean purge`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342978/what-will-happen-if-i-run-%27rosclean-purge%27?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-01-31

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, what that's going to do is remove the ROS logs from your `.ros/log` directory. When packages print to screen or have debug messages, they also get logged in that directory.

Over time if nothing empties them, it'll keep piling up. This warning is to let you know that there are alot of logs laying around, and you may want to get rid of them so they don't keep growing.

All that `rosclean purge` does is remove those files.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2020-01-31**:
Thank you, it works without any issues!